# how to upload big data to a host with webclient

Tags: c#, file-upload, webclient

i need a function to upload a big data file to a server as HTTP upload with POST from an external service provider.
in the moment i use the following weblient function and it works with smaller files:

```
_byteReturn = await _webClient.UploadDataTaskAsync(_url, File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\tmp\test.zip"));
```

but in that case exist the problem with 2GB border and the function ReadAllBytes() read all bytes to the memory.
of course i could use the another weblient funtion

```
_byteReturn = await _webClient.UploadFileTaskAsync(_url, @"c:\tmp\test.zip"));
```

but with that function i get a an HTTP error 400 from the server. :/
so it try to use my own code for the upload.

```
using (WebClient _webClient = new WebClient())
{
    _webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Test";
    _webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl] = "no-cache";
    _webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Basic {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Username") + ":" + ("Password" )));

    using (StreamWriter _output = new StreamWriter(await _webClient.OpenWriteTaskAsync(_url)))
    {

        _output.AutoFlush = true;


        using (FileStream _fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\tmp\install.esd", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            _bytesRead = 0;
            _readByteBuffer = new byte[_bufferLength];
            _bytesToRead = _fileStream.Length;


#if DEBUG

            FileStream _testOutFileStream = new FileStream(_writeTestFileNameZip, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
#endif
            do
            {
                _fileStream.Seek(_bytesRead, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                _readCount = _fileStream.Read(_readByteBuffer, 0, _bufferLength);
                _output.Write(_readByteBuffer);

#if DEBUG
                if (_testOutFileStream != null)
                { 
                    _testOutFileStream.Write(_readByteBuffer, 0, _readCount);
                    _testOutFileStream.Flush();
                }
#endif
                _bytesRead += _readCount;
            }
            while (_readCount > 0);

#if DEBUG
            if (_testOutFileStream != null)
                _testOutFileStream.Dispose();
#endif
        }

        if (_output != null)
            _output.Close();
    }
}
```

the point is 'IT WORKS'. i get no error during the upload and i get the right answer from the server after the upload is finished BUT the upload is fast like hell.(uploading 1GB wit a 10MBit/s in 10 seconds).

i believe it is a cache problem, but i am not sure. who know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the code below and let me know if it fixes it for you, you'll need to reconfigure your variables/etc...

```
string _username = string.Empty;
string _password = string.Empty;
string _url = "http://example.com";
string _writeTestFileNameZip = string.Empty;

using (WebClient _webClient = new WebClient())
{
    _webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Test";
    _webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl] = "no-cache";
    _webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = $"{Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{_username}:{_password}"))}";


    using (Stream _output = await _webClient.OpenWriteTaskAsync(_url))
    using (FileStream _fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\tmp\install.esd", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        byte[] _readByteBuffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
        long _bytesToRead = _fileStream.Length;
        int _bytesRead = 0;

        _fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        while ((_bytesRead = await _fileStream.ReadAsync(_readByteBuffer, 0, _readByteBuffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            await _output.WriteAsync(_readByteBuffer, 0, _bytesRead);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thx for that tip and yes it works but strange. 
the point is, that i waiting for the server response and in my version i get the response directly after the upload, means everything is ok but the upload can not be finished.
with your version is the upload(the writing of the bytes) also very fast like in my version, but then the program is waiting for the server response till the upload is really finished.
so i am a one step ahead, but i must show the user the progress in real time AND the stupid program load the upload data still in the memory. ((

Answer (score 0):

based on Aydin Adn and my additional searches, i found the final solution. 
it is necessary to set the **AllowWriteStreamBuffering** property to false. that is not possible with the original webclient, but in a expansion class. in my case was it very easy, because i already wrote my own webclient to work with the response data. there i overrided the function **GetWebRequest** with the following code:

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri _uri)
{

    HttpWebRequest _webRequest = base.GetWebRequest(_uri) as HttpWebRequest;

    if (_webRequest != null)
    {
        // no buffer
        _webRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
        // if data size overhanded in constructur(necessary with AllowWriteStreamBuffering ==  false)
        if (this.ContentLength > 0)
            _webRequest.ContentLength = this.ContentLength;
        // if NO data size overhanded in constructur(necessary with AllowWriteStreamBuffering ==  false)
        else
            _webRequest.SendChunked = true;
        // if timeout overhanded in constructur
        if (this.TimeOut > 0)
            _webRequest.Timeout = this.TimeOut * 1000;

        return (_webRequest);
    }
    else
        return (null);
}
```